# How to build an SDK style project for the sl5 target framework?

Tags: c#, .net-core, silverlight

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks `sl5` is a supported target framework for an SDK style project.

My project file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;sl5</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Yet, I cannot build it:

```
C:\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes [master ≡ +0 ~1 -0 !]> dotnet build                                                                                                  Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+b89cb5fde for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes\src\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes.csproj (in 176 ms).
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(93,5): error NETSDK1013: The TargetFramework value 'sl5' was not recognized. It may be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly. [C:\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes\src\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes.csproj]
  DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes -> C:\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes\src\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\DataSourceCodeGenerator.Attributes.dll

Build FAILED.
```

I am OK to build any target framework that will be recognized by a Silverlight project. So, if there is an alternative to `sl5` - that works too.

P.S.

Please, do not ask why I need to build a Silverlight project.

Comment: Not a surprise. They usually forget to remove things they don't want to support any more.

Comment: That is not very helpful :-(

Comment: If you look for alternatives, https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8779 and https://github.com/novotnyllc/MSBuildSdkExtras should be your guide. It's just a few clicks on Google.

Comment: @LexLi - please convert your comment to answer. I was able to build sl5 with MSBuild.Sdk.Extras albeit using msbuild.

Comment: @LexLi - could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476439/how-to-target-sl5-with-dotnet-exe-and-msbuild-sdk-extras ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from the comments.

Microsoft documentation can be inaccurate in certain pages, and I believe this is one of such pages.

You cannot use .NET Core SDK's default settings to multi target Silverlight platforms, but with some help from the open source `MSBuild.Sdk.Extras` you can achieve the same.

#### References

- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8779
- https://github.com/novotnyllc/MSBuildSdkExtras