# How to target sl5 with dotnet.exe and MSBuild.Sdk.Extras?

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild

This post is related to [How to build an SDK style project for the sl5 target framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63456608/how-to-build-an-sdk-style-project-for-the-sl5-target-framework?noredirect=1#comment112218734_63456608)

So I managed to target sl5 with the following project file:

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.1.2">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>sl5</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

However, it only works with `msbuild.exe`, not `dotnet.exe`. The root cause is - dotnet.exe does not see the registry settings that locate the Silverlight framework code, because they are only found under

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\ReferenceAssemblies\SLRuntimeInstallPath
```

- msbuild.exe sees it because it is a 32 bits process - **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe**
- dotnet.exe does not see it, because it is a 64 bits process - **C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe**

I would like to be able to use `dotnet.exe` anyway. I see two options:

1. Replicate the necessary keys where dotnet.exe can see them - does not seem a good option in general.
2. Have my own adhoc build code that would search on WOW6432Node regardless of the process bitness and set the required build properties beforehand. That should satisfy the build.

Am I missing anything else? Some simple way to let dotnet.exe see the WOW6432Node registry?

Comment: I think you should talk to the developers directly, https://github.com/novotnyllc/MSBuildSdkExtras/issues

Comment: It is not a problem with MSBuildSdkExtras. It is how Silverlight installation writes to WOW6432Node and how dotnet.exe does not see it being a 64 bits process vs msbuild being a 32 bits process

Comment: @LexLi - BTW, is this your article - https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-install-microsoft-cors-module-for-iis-express-7ac24e4c3bc4 ?

Comment: You can install 32 bit .NET Core SDK to see if that resolves the issue, but I think MSBuildSDKExtras can be improved to support 32 bit Silverlight tooling in 64 bit mode. That’s why I asked you to contact it’s authors. Yeah, that’s my blog post.

Comment: But how can it be improved if I am running the 64 bits version of dotnet.exe? Do you mean they will implement something like the option (2) in my list of options I see to fix it?

Comment: A 64 bit process can see and call 32 bit executable, so there is no technical barrier and just some efforts. But a 32 bit executable requires some hack (like disabling WOW64 redirection) to call 64 bit executable. The authors should know better how to resolve that, but since Silverlight is no more a feasible option (end of life in 2021), not sure whether they would like to fix that for you.